Golomb's self-describing sequence problem
Inspired by this problem.
Golomb's self-describing sequence g(n) is a sequence where any natural number n is repeated within the sequence g(n) times.
Given an input of \$ n \$, output: $$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} g(i) \right)^2 \mod 998244353$$
Limitations: \$ 0 \leq n \leq 10^{18} \$
Example: If \$ n = 4 \$, $$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{4} g(i) \right)^2 = (1 + 2 + 2 + 3)^2 = 64 \mod 998244353 = 64$$

Welcome to Code Golf. Giving an output reduced modulo an arbitrary constant is a common practice on other sites such as Codeforces. If this challenge is taken from another site, please make sure you're allowed to publish it here and add due credits.

Also, why not just output $g(n)$? Computing the sum of squares modulo a constant seems like unnecessary fluff

I think the bulk of this problem (that is the part of it which most the interesting or creative golfing can happen) is calculating the sequence. So I am inclined to say this is a duplicate of the linked challenge.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 67 bytes
Try it online!
f@1=1;f@n_:=1+f[n-f@f[n-1]]
g@n_:=Sum[f[i]~Mod~998244353,{i,1,n}]^2


I think it can't do $ n = 10^{18} $.

@shlby696 By default, [tag:code-golf] solutions don't have to output within a reasonable time or work on a normal computer. If you want to restrict solutions, you can make a challenge with [tag:restricted-time] or [tag:restricted-complexity], describing exactly what the requirements are.
